# c# NetworkStream.Read error Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I am building a socket server made of c#.
The client sends a ping packet once a second.
The server then periodically delivers ping packets to the client.
When about 20 devices are connected to the server, the following error occurs after a short period of time.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A
>
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host
>
> has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>
> failed to respond
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
>
> at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()

When that error occurs, it occurs simultaneously for almost all connected client sockets.
ReceivedTimeout and SendTimeout of the server socket were changed from 3 seconds to 10 seconds.But there is an error in the same way.

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for more than three d

It is being developed through asp.net and distributed through iis.

```
void ReceiveRunnable()        
{

            log.Debug($"Start 'Receive Runnable'");
            try
            {

                int exceptionCount = 0;

                string line;

                while (IsRun)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (socket != null && (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            exceptionCount = 0;

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                            {
                                // Ping Packet
                                if (line[0] == '0')
                                {
                                    ReceivePingPacket(line);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    buffer.Enqueue(line);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        log.Error(e + "   e:" + e.SocketErrorCode);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        if (IsRun)
                        {
                            log.Error(e);
                            break;
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (IsRun)
                {
                    log.Error(e);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Close();
                OnDisconnect?.Invoke(this);
            }
            log.Debug($"Stop 'Receive Runnable'");
        }
```

Comment: First the Network card responds to PING messages and your server code is doing nothing.  The PING at the clients is not working.  The PING message has a timeout and it seems all the devices are timing out at the same time because they are never getting any responses.  Start simple by opening a cmd.exe and test to see if PING is actually working.  Try both the PC NAME and IP address to see which is working and which is not working.  Probably the Computer Name is working and the IP is not working.  Then try doing a ping from server to client.  PING can work in one direction and not in other.

Comment: Can I ping it and test it for disconnection from the network?
Because there are many connected devices, it is hard to ping the cmd.
So if you create a new server, a client, and two different servers, and the same problem occurs at the same time, is it a network problem?

Comment: The ping tests devices, not Server software.  Every device build into the Ethernet hardware responds to a PING message.  You do not need to install or run any software.  Creating a Server does nothing.  You software is client software that is sending a ping to a hardware device and getting a response.  When you ping a do not get a response it means the device doesn't exist and you will reach the catch when the timeout is reached.

Comment: understood. I'll test it and give you the results.
What if there is no problem with ping or there is a problem?
If there is a problem with the ping, is the router lacking performance?

Comment: The PING using Computer name should work.  Ping using IP requires the Masks on Ethernet interfaces (including routers) to be set correctly.